# How to show specific list of rows in UITableView in same section in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm a newbie in Swift. I have to implement alphabet list on right side of table view, as in Apple's contact list.

[image: Demo image]

Is it possible to implement it on same section only. i.e. there is only one section?

As I have only one section And I don't want to add header before every specific row.
I want to reach that row which starts with specific alphabet.

There are many examples by using multiple section but I did not find any explanation of how to do this by single section.
If there is any way please share.
Thanks in advance.

I created

```
  var arrIndexSection : NSArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","#"]
```

and use this func to show right side array

```
  func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return arrIndexSection as! [String]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let name = arrayOfName?


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

        cell.lbl_Name.text = name
}
```

which shows the array list 
after this I'm clueless what to do

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that also with one section but you have to make 2 cells one for content and other as the one holds the alphabet sure this needs to manage the data source array carefully and this to simulate the headerView that you might have if it's a multiSection tableView

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
is it possible without header

Comment: header in multiSection , another cell for alphabet in your wanted implementation

Comment: are array of alphabet Get by sectionIndexTitles refers to section only?.

Comment: it's only one array first index contains "A" then all items under it say from index 1....10 , then index 11 contains "B" and so on , in cellForRow you will detect if the string is one charater then it's alphabet otherwise it's a subitem